# Escaping a percent symbol in zsh

Tags: escaping, zsh

How would I add a percent symbol to a variable in zsh?

```
export number_e164='%2B12125551234';
echo $number_e164;
```

Returns

```
1m12125551234%2B12125551234
```

on my machine.

[This article](http://wiki.zoelife4u.org/index.php/Zsh%3aPrompt_Control_Sequences) suggests using two percent symbols in a row - `%%` to get one percent.

However running:

```
export number_e164='%%2B12125551234';
echo $number_e164;
```

Returns

```
%%2B12125551234
```

Which is two percents. How do I get just one percent symbol?

Comment: That returns `1m15005550001\%2B15005550001`.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, your initial variant shows just what it is supposed to show (by the way, beware of echo unescaping escape sequences by default, use `echo -E` to prevent it or just `typeset number_e164`, it will show the variable value).

Comment: And what does `typeset number_e164` after running initial `export number_e164='%2B12125551234'` show? Does the result change if you replace `export` with `typeset -x` (they should be the same) or with `builtin typeset -x`? And you don’t need `;` at the end of commands (it must not harm though).

Comment: I moved my .zshrc and tried the first variation again and it works now. I'll try to narrow down the issue in my zshrc file.